# Dataframe to postgresql table

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

I need to insert a dataframe to our postgresql table, but when sending the dataframe to our postgresql table, it for some reason changes order of the rows. Following code is used to send the dataframe to our postgresql table.

```
def postgresql(df, table):

    # Connect to the PostgreSQL server
    engine = create_engine(f'postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@{server}:5432/{database}')
    df.to_csv("test.csv")
    # Send dataframe to PostgreSQL table in database. Replace, if already exist
    df.to_sql(table, engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)

    return df
```

`df.to_csv("test.csv")` creates a csv file names 'test', and this csv file looks like the following. Do notice that the tokens are ordered (not alphabetically), and number is ordered in ascending manner, based on their token:

```
     number   name        address         city           token
0    1        Alarm       oxstreet 12     Reading        eng
1    2        Computer    pentaroad 4     Oxford         eng
2    3        Music       thisstreet 2    London         eng
3    4        School      schoolroad 45   London         eng
4    1        Hospital    madstreet 24    Manchester     Owx
5    2        Bowling     placestreet 5   Birmingham     Owx
6    1        Hotel       cemstreet 24    Liverpool      JOC
7    2        Paintball   shootstreet 2   Manchester     JOC
8    3        Center      examstreet 24   Bristol        JOC
9    4        Computer    comproad 24     Brigthon       JOC
```

Although, `df.to_sql(table, engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)` uploads the following to the sql table:

```
     number   name        address         city           token
0    1        Alarm       oxstreet 12     Reading        eng
1    3        Center      examstreet 24   Bristol        JOC
2    2        Computer    pentaroad 4     Oxford         eng
3    3        Music       thisstreet 2    London         eng
4    4        School      schoolroad 45   London         eng
5    1        Hospital    madstreet 24    Manchester     Owx
6    2        Bowling     placestreet 5   Birmingham     Owx
7    1        Hotel       cemstreet 24    Liverpool      JOC
8    2        Paintball   shootstreet 2   Manchester     JOC
9    4        Computer    comproad 24     Brigthon       JOC
```

Above, is the table, which can be seen on the postgres table, and this is very odd to me, as dataframe just before inserting to the postgres table, looks different than this, so how and why is this changed on the postgres table. Anyone who has experience in this? Perhaps, i should try another way of inserting to postgres table. How can i do that?

Comment: i dont think SQL orders rows by default, so your output does not look odd. I could be wrong though, so have a look at postgres docs regarding row order

Answer (score 0):

For SQL the order is not important. You can use: `ORDER_BY` and check your query by `dump` the result into a .csv file. I guess you want to postprocess the result from the query in pandas/ qgis again.